# loader-wizard.php?timeout=0&ini=0&page=loader_check

Tags: php, synology

The following problems have been found with the ionCube Loader installation:

```
The following ini files could not be found by the Wizard: /volume1/@appstore/PHP7.3/misc/php-fpm.ini,/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php_profile/b9a41bca-af4e-11e9-9fc0-6335258c6d96/conf.d/user_settings.ini,/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php_profile/b9a41bca-af4e-11e9-9fc0-6335258c6d96/conf.d/webstation_vhost.ini,/run/php-fpm/conf.d/timezone.ini
This may be due to server restrictions in place.
The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration.
```

Comment: It would be great if you could phrase the actual question clearly :) - like what you did, then the error that occured, and then what you have tried/analyzed to far

Comment: I put my url like this: 
http://mywebsite/ioncube/loader-wizard.php. 

It change to. 

http://mywebsite/ioncube/loader-wizard.php?timeout=0&ini=0&page=default

Comment: I put my url like this: 
http://mywebsite/ioncube/loader-wizard.php.

It change to. 

http://mywebsite/ioncube/loader-wizard.php?timeout=0&ini=0&page=default.  

Then I have this error.  

exist with the ionCube Loader installation:
The following ini files could not be found by the Wizard: /volume1/@appstore/PHP7.3/misc/php-fpm.ini,/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php_profile/b9a41bca-af4e-11e9-9fc0-6335258c6d96/conf.d/user_settings.ini,/usr/syno/etc/packages/WebStation/php_profile/b9a41bca-af4e-11e9-9fc0-6335258c6d96/conf.d/webstation_vhost.ini,/run/php-fpm/conf.d/timezone.ini

Comment: I meant editing your question, not adding comments.